# How do I prevent Ubuntu from updating certain packages?

Tags: ubuntu, xorg, updates

I have Ubuntu 10.10 installed on a Thinkpad machine. Recently I installed NVidia CUDA on it. The installation was successful, thanks to this very helpful [guide](http://vgerscorner.wordpress.com/2010/10/24/opencl-ubuntu-install-guide/).

Unfortunately, the X server stopped working after the latest software update/upgrade. I could use the shell, but doing `sudo /etc/init.d/gdm stop` and then `start` never helped. Doing `Ctrl + Alt + F7` changed the screen to the boot log (all those messages that are shown if you load Ubuntu in the failsafe mode). No Gnome, no graphical log-in window.

I reinstalled Ubuntu 10.10 on another partition and reinstalled CUDA. NVidia's dev driver works and I would like to prevent my new Ubuntu from doing this kind of dangerous upgrades again. But still I would like to do `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade` for all the other packages on the system.

**How can I do updates to Ubuntu while excluding NVidia video drivers (and all that xorg.conf stuff) from being updated?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd either need to use [pinning or holding packages](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PinningHowto) from your package manager - holding seems easier - by the looks of things holding is easier

You can do it from your package manager with the 'lock version' option or with dpkg with the command `echo packagename hold | dpkg --set-selections` . See the link i linked earlier for more details